# how to raise a timeout error manually?

Tags: ruby, http

I want to test a http get request. output something if timeout.

```
  begin
      url = "#{url}?#{params.to_param}"
      Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
  rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "....."
  end
```

How to raise a timeout error manually? or how to set a shorter timeout number for http request?

For a http request, should I change the default timeout number? How long is appropriate？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set timeout use:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(host_param) 
http.read_timeout = 500
```

There are few types of timeouts you can set. From [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

- `open_timeout`:
  Number of seconds to wait for the connection to open. 
  Any number may be used, including Floats for fractional seconds. 
  If the HTTP object cannot open a connection in this many seconds, 
  it raises a Net::OpenTimeout exception. The default value is nil.
- `read_timeout`:
  Number of seconds to wait for one block to be read (via one read(2) call). 
  Any number may be used, including Floats for fractional seconds. 
  If the HTTP object cannot read data in this many seconds, 
  it raises a Net::ReadTimeout exception. The default value is 60 seconds.
- `ssl_timeout`:
  Sets the SSL timeout seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2008/04/24/adding-timeout-to-nethttp-get_response/

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

http.read_timeout = 5
http.open_timeout = 5
resp = http.start() {|http|
http.get(url.path)
}
puts resp.kind_of? Net::HTTPResponse
puts resp.code
puts resp.body
```